# How to embed facebook post along with comments?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

Spending a lot of time one figuring out that how to embed facebook posts along with comments, I came up with the idea to embed posts and comment separately using plugins and iterate over comments.

Post:

```
{% for post in pids %}
    <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/rio2016/posts/{{ post }}" data-width="750"></div>
    <div class="fb-comment-embed" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10102735452532991?comment_id=1070233703036185" data-width="750"></div>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments" data-width="750" data-numposts="2"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

But it differs a lot in design than a post on facebook.

Looks like below:

[Screenshot of post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Lm7.png)

Is there any other way which can facilitate to embed an arbitrary public post along with associated comments?